# Where Can I Download an Older Version of Tails?

Tags: tails

I'm wondering if anyone can point me to where I can download an older version of Tails, since https://dl.amnesia.boum.org/obsolete no longer works, and neither does https://archive.org.

Thanks for your help in advance!